# Как на C# "перевернуть" строку: было - 123, стало - 321?

Tags: c#, строки

Как на C# "перевернуть" строку: было - 123, стало - 321?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
using System;

static class StringHelper
{
    public static string ReverseString(string s)
    {
    char[] arr = s.ToCharArray();
    Array.Reverse(arr);
    return new string(arr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, именно то, что нужно, спасибо

Comment: да ладно:

    "str".Reverse().Aggregate(string.Empty, (acc, ch)=>acc+ch);

Comment: В моём случае, читаемость важнее, чем производительность, ибо там хватает долговременных операций :)

Comment: Можно короче конечно:

    string input = "hello world";
string output = new string(input.ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());

Answer (score 17):

- `new string(s.Reverse().ToArray());`
- Все методы, которые вам предложили *(включая и мой),* не подходят для серьезного продакшн кода, поскольку, например, не учитывают расстановку [`Acute Accents`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent), которые при реверсе окажутся перед неправильным знаком, а также будут реверсить [суррогатные пары в `UTF-16`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), фактически, "ломая" корректную юникодную строку.
- Подробнее насчет этих подводных камней - [`Jon Skeet, C# in Depth - 1.7.2.`](http://csharpindepth.com/)

Comment: Т.е. правильный алгоритм это сначала перевести строку в массив UCS, реверсировать его, а потом перевести UCS в строку в исходной кодировке.

Comment: @avp

- Да, можно сделать так, как вы предлагаете (собственно, в любой юникодный формат типа `UCS / UTF32 / ...`, в которых эти элементы представляются одним `code point'ом`). 

- Еще можно сделать итератор именно по `code points,` а не `code units`, который будет реверсить суррогатные пары как единое целое. Другое дело, что проблема с диакритическими знаками все равно остается и решить ее в общем виде - это нетривиальная задача. Плюс, наверняка, есть и другие проблемы, о которых я не знаю / не задумывался.

Comment: А разве диакритические знаки не входят в UTF-32/UCS? 

Всегда считал, что для всех этих "знаков со шляпкой" (или я ошибаюсь и "диакритические знаки" это нечто другое?) есть символы юникода.

Comment: @avp

- Я сам недавно узнал, что, можно использовать так называемые [`Combining Code Points`,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) и в этом случае у нас получается 2 юникодных `code point'a` на один видимый символ, а можно пользоваться [`Precomposed Characters,`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precomposed_character) где, грубо говоря, диакритические знаки уже "встроены" в символ.

- Так вот, понятно, что в первом случае `UTF-32` не спасет.

Comment: @avp

- На вики (`Precomposed Characters`) по этому поводу даже сказано, что:
> ... the two solutions are equivalent and **should render identically.**

Comment: @Котик, спасибо. Очень интересно. Надо будет поподробнее ознакомиться.

--

Вот ведь дурь-то, а? Только что казалось, что юникод спасает от всех проблем с символами переменной длины, и на тебе...

Откровенно не могу понять, почему 32-х (ну, 31-го) бит не хватило?

Comment: @avp Как я понимаю, `UTF` и вообще все юникодные стандарты хорошо описывает [**вот эта картинка**](http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/standards.png) :)

Comment: Точно, @Котик.  Мне это напомнило **восемнадцать** (или что-то около) однобайтных кодировок кириллицы.

Answer (score 0):

```
  private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int n = textBox5.Text.Length;
            char[] mas = new char[n];
            for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
            {
                mas[i] = textBox5.Text[i];
            }
            for (int i = n; i != 0; i--)
            {
                label4.Text += mas[i-1];
            }
        }
```

Данный код позволит перевернуть любую строку.

Comment: Сравните свой уровень ответа с ответами данными ранее. ИМХО, я бы на Вашем месте снес свой ответ.

Answer (score 0):

var result = string.Join("", yourString.Reverse());

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]